# Newly Built Computer from old parts - Ubuntu 14.04 - Kdenlive 0.9.6-5ubuntu1 - to Kdenlive lastest version?

Tags: kdenlive

I have recently built a computer from components I had lying around - The motherboard is Asrock H61M-DGS with UEFI which I have no experience with - I tried to install the latest version of Ubuntu (version 18.10) I think it was - this did not install because apparently the UEFI stopped it - I could not find legacy bios or secure boot.

I think tried Lixux Mint 19 I think - same result/

So I thought give it one last try and try to install Ubuntu 14.04 I think it was LTS, anyway it installed without problems and very stable.

Because I wanted to do some video editing I installed Kdenlive from the Ubuntu Software Center, also installed okay - I then realised the version installed is very old Version 0.9.6-5ubuntu1.

I took a look at Kdenlive website and saw the latest version as 18.12 so thought maybe I could install this version, but of course I have to now ask the question will it install on my old version Ubuntu or will I have problems.

I followed instructions to install the Kdenlive PPA but all seemed okay but at the end there were three errors (which I did not record - sorry) anyway the PPA is in the Software and Update tab so I guess it's okay?

Sorry this is long winded - Now can I install the latest version and if so how can I do it - probably the terminal - but do I have to remove the old version first? or can I have the two versions, only removing the old one if the updated Kdenlive works?

Thanks

Comment: I would focus on getting 18.04 or 18.10 installed, and not how to get up to date on a single piece of software. There's no reason why 18.04 should not work on that hardware :)

Comment: Wish I knew how to do that - I have no experience with UEFI only ever had windows 7 ultimate on motherboards that support the old bios system. As I understand it there should be an option in UEFI for turning on Legacy Bios and turning of secure boot which according to some peeps will allow me to install the most recent version of Ubuntu.